# MatchTemplate in OpenCV with Python

Tags: python, opencv

I'm using opencv with python bindings.  I'm trying to use the template match, but it's not performing exactly as I need it to.  If there is no image matching the template I supply it, I don't want it to return a match.  It seems to always return a match whether the actual template exists at all in the image I supply it.

I've looked at the documentation for the opencv with Python and can't seem to find any mention of how to set a minimum threshold for matching templates.  I need it to be relatively strict when comparing the template to the image.

```
image = LoadImage("c:/image.png")

template = LoadImage("c:/image-crop2.png")

W,H = GetSize(image)

w,h = GetSize(template)

width = W - w + 1

height = H - h + 1

result = CreateImage((width, height), 32, 1)

MatchTemplate(image, template, result, CV_TM_CCORR)

(min_x, max_y, minloc, maxloc) = MinMaxLoc(result)

(x, y) = minloc

print result
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this answer: [OpenCV. Drawing rectangle when matching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7580796/opencv-drawing-rectangle-when-matching/7582212#7582212)

You are having exactly the same problem - `MatchTemplate` returns a kind of similarity map instead of single match position.