# Draw square only when template matches (template matching)

Tags: python, templates, opencv

I am trying to do template matching with opencv/python. It works fine on the video meaning that it finds the object when it is in the screen and bounds the matched object with a rectangle. However, when the object is not there, the bounding rectangle just sort of drifts.

Is there a way to say, "if the templates are not the same, don't draw the rectangle"?

I thought maybe if I took the return value of the template matching method and then created a threshold saying "if the numbers in the array are above the level, draw the rectangle," but the image array is too large to do that.

I am following the tutorial here: http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_tutorials.html

There is a similar question here: [OpenCV. Drawing rectangle when matching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7580796/opencv-drawing-rectangle-when-matching) but I was confused by the answer because I thought min_value was simply a coordinate for where to draw the rectangle.

```
#template matching
edges2 = edges.copy()
template = cv2.imread("hand.jpg",0)
w,h = template.shape[::-1]
edges = edges2.copy()
method = eval('cv2.TM_CCOEFF')
res = cv2.matchTemplate(edges,template,method)
min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv2.minMaxLoc(res)
top_left = max_loc
bottom_right = (top_left[0] + w, top_left[1] + h)
cv2.rectangle(frame,top_left, bottom_right, 255, 2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`max_val` returned by `minMaxLoc()` can be used for the threshold you're looking for. If the detection is very good, this value will be highest (1, if I recall).

Comment: I got numbers in the millions when I started printing out max_val, but it is definitely a threshold.

Comment: In C++ interface, a `CV_32FC1` image has its range from 0 to 1. I'm not aware of Python's way of storing it. Not sure, but maybe NumPy has a better solution?

Comment: you mean in terms of getting a value for the threshold? I am using NumPy arrays for the video frames, so I assumed(maybe a bad thing) that the max_val was coming from a NumPy calculation.

Comment: Maybe you can scale it into a range like [0 1], and then threshold. I will not be able to try this now, so I can't give you more details.